# Gevent functions aren't running asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, gevent, eel

In [this Gevent tutorial](https://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/) it goes over how to spawn multiple threads to run asynchronously.

```
import gevent
import random

def task(pid):
    """
    Some non-deterministic task
    """
    gevent.sleep(random.randint(0,2)*0.001)
    print('Task %s done' % pid)

def synchronous():
    for i in range(1,10):
        task(i)

def asynchronous():
    threads = [gevent.spawn(task, i) for i in xrange(10)]
    gevent.joinall(threads)

print('Synchronous:')
synchronous()

print('Asynchronous:')
asynchronous()
```

Results

```
Synchronous:
Task 1 done
Task 2 done
Task 3 done
Task 4 done
Task 5 done
Task 6 done
Task 7 done
Task 8 done
Task 9 done
Asynchronous:
Task 1 done
Task 5 done
Task 6 done
Task 2 done
Task 4 done
Task 7 done
Task 8 done
Task 9 done
Task 0 done
Task 3 done
```

This works as I expected. However, when I replace the trivial sleep task with a 'working' task, it doesn't work the same way...

```
import gevent
import random

def task(pid):
    start_time = time.time()
    array = []
    for x in range(0, 1000000):
        x = str(x) + "WasteMyTime"
        array.append(x)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Task " + str(pid) + " took  " + str(elapsed_time))

def synchronous():
    for i in range(1,10):
        task(i)

def asynchronous():
    threads = [gevent.spawn(task, i) for i in range(10)]
    gevent.joinall(threads)

print('Synchronous:')
synchronous()

print('Asynchronous:')
asynchronous()
```

Results

```
Synchronous:
Task 1 took  0.3065943717956543
Task 2 took  0.2897024154663086
Task 3 took  0.29267001152038574
Task 4 took  0.2936718463897705
Task 5 took  0.28526878356933594
Task 6 took  0.29134082794189453
Task 7 took  0.28323960304260254
Task 8 took  0.28522467613220215
Task 9 took  0.28423142433166504
Asynchronous:
Task 0 took  0.2896885871887207
Task 1 took  0.2837369441986084
Task 2 took  0.28224802017211914
Task 3 took  0.2857201099395752
Task 4 took  0.28621697425842285
Task 5 took  0.28621697425842285
Task 6 took  0.28621602058410645
Task 7 took  0.2857208251953125
Task 8 took  0.28720879554748535
Task 9 took  0.2847275733947754
```

The asynchronous tasks each slowly print out one after the other and the entire asynchronous block took just as long as the synchronous block. Is this user error?

Comment: You either need to monkey patch or use `gevent.time`.  Monkey patch is WAAAY easier.

Answer (score 2):

Add this on the top of your script(1st line of your script)

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

Comment: Adding the patch did not work. The "Asynchronous" results still print out one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

`gevent` is mostly used for I/O-bound operations. Your task is CPU-bound. Only one greenlet can be run at a time.

To see the impact of `gevent`, you should perform an I/O-bound task. Below is a modified example that makes a network request.

```
import time

import gevent
from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()

import requests


def task(pid):
    start_time = time.time()
    requests.get('http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204')
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Task " + str(pid) + " took  " + str(elapsed_time))


def synchronous():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        task(i)


def asynchronous():
    threads = [gevent.spawn(task, i) for i in range(10)]
    gevent.joinall(threads)


print('Synchronous:')
synchronous()

print('Asynchronous:')
asynchronous()
```